# Prove that among any 12 consecutive positive integers there is at least one which is smaller than the sum of its proper divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Prove that among any 12 consecutive positive integers
there is at least one which is smaller than the sum of
its proper divisors. (The proper divisors of a positive
integer n are all positive integers other than 1 and n
which divide n. For example, the proper divisors of 14 are 2 
and 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Among any $12$ consecutive positive integers, there is one that is a multiple of $12$.

Can you show that $12n$ is smaller than the sum of its divisors for any positive integer $n$?

Comment: $d(12)=2+3+4+6=15>12$... Ooops, I read the question "opposite" (which is why I had a hard time proving it)

Comment: ^Yes, $12$ is smaller than the sum of its proper divisors. EDIT: Yeah, I initially read the question the other way as well, which caused me to take a long time with it.

Comment: In fact, among any 6 consecutive integers _greater than 6_ there is one such number, because $6n$ is strictly [abundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) for any $n$ strictly greater than 1.

Comment: @barakmanos Since every 6th number, starting from 12, is abundant, there is a limit to the number of consecutive _deficient_ number you can get. But if you reverse the inequality, there is no limit to the number of consecutive _abundant_ numbers you can have. This is proved in comments by Jianing Song in [A094268](https://oeis.org/A094268).