# Proving existence of abundant integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that among any 12 consecutive integers, there exists at least one integer whose sum of proper divisors (divisors excluding 1 and the number itself) is greater than itself (said integer is abundant).
So far, I have tried using the formula $$\sigma(n) = \prod_{i = 1}^{k} \frac{p_i^{a_i + 1} - 1}{p_i -1}$$ hence deriving an inequality for a single such number that I need to prove which I don't know how to proceed with: $$\prod p_i^{a_i + 1} - 1 > 2 \left (\prod p_i^{a_i + 1} - p_i^{a_i} \right) + \prod p_i - 1$$
Could you please point out why this logic is faulty? A hint would also be greatly appreciated.
I am aware there is a duplicate question (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842170) but the answer stops at the part where my question arises.

Comment: See the Wikipedia article [abundant number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) for more on the topic.

Comment: So I need to use the property where the multiple of an abundant number is also abundant? What if I wanted to generalise?

Comment: Any $12$ consecutive positive integers must contain exactly two multiples of $6$, both of which must be abundant (unless one of them is $6$, which is perfect).

Comment: Yes, I do get the property; but I think what I'm more concerned with is how I could derive that property (or some result that gives me a condition for checking an integer to be abundant using its PPF) from the formula that I tried applying. The proof given in the Wikipedia page uses an example to show that the property holds true.

Comment: On a separate note, you're overusing $n$ in your first formula, where you are using $n$ both as an argument for $\sigma$ and as an index for prime factors (in the product formula on the right hand side).

Comment: I don't think you can prove the result with a general prime factorization of a single number (since it isn't true for all prime factorizations). I think you need to use something along the lines of Geoffrey Trang's comment; or that among $12$ consecutive (positive) integers there is a multiple of $12$, which must be abundant because...(try to think of specific factors of an integer of the form $12t$ (with $t>0$) that sum up to more than $12t$).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.